# PHP - Parallel downloads

Tags: php

i would like to use parallel downloads of images, because currently i have more than 40 images on my website . I have two subdomains images01 and images02 containing  the same images but right now my images are showing just from images01 subdomain . Is it possible half of images to be shown from images01 and the other half  from images02 ?

Here is my code

```
// file image URL
function file_image_url($image_name, $image_location) {
    global $settings;
    return ($image_location == 1) ? 'http://images01.' . 'mysite.com/img/' . rawurlencode($image_name) : $image_name;
}
```

Comment: `return (rand(1,2) == 1)  ? 'http://images01'... : 'http://images02'...`. But you're better off letting a CDN do this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are after some sort of load balancing, however the way you're implementing it seems to be misguided.  Read up on round-robin load balancing - that can get you started.

Comment: You're not going to see any difference in speed by downloading from different subdomains.  Use a CDN or perhaps lazy load using JavaScript (there are many jQuery plugins available for this).